# Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Profile[]>'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

```
profileData : Observable<Profile>;

async ionViewWillLoad(){
    await this.afAuth.authState.take(1).subscribe(data => { 
       if (data && data.email && data.uid){
            this.newProfile = this.afDatabase.object(`profile/${data.uid}`).valueChanges();
        }
    })
}
```

i'am getting error in `this.newProfile`

> Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.

and

> Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Observable'. Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Profile'. Property 'username' is missing in type '{}'.

this is about.ts

Comment: can you add more information. what is the type of `newProfile`

Comment: try any instead of {}

Comment: how do you expect anyone to understand what you are doing when you dont post the complete code?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the type returned by `valueChanges` Observable is implicitly an `Object`, which, of course, is not assignable to type `Profile`. Try type-casting it explicitly:

```
async ionViewWillLoad(){
await this.afAuth.authState.take(1).subscribe(data => { 
   if (data && data.email && data.uid){
        this.newProfile = <Observable<Profile>>this.afDatabase.object(`profile/${data.uid}`).valueChanges();
    }
})
```

}

Comment: I believe there was another method to have the return data cast as the type you want but my memory fails me. Thank you very much for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
Observable<any>;
```

just set it to any or make sure the returned value is of type profile.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove the type declaration from `profileData`? This worked for me.

`profileData;` instead of `profileData : Observable<Profile>;`